# SQL is null in CASE statement and JOIN 3 tables?

Tags: sql-server

use Tables:
`[AdventureWorks2012].[Production].[ProductInventory]`,
`[Production].[Product]`,
`[Production].[Location]`

columns: 
`ProductID`,
`Name`,
`ProductLine` (if null value,display N/A,if M,display 'Mountain',if T display 'Touring',all other-s ,display 'others'),
`SellStartDate`,
`LocationID`,
`Availability`,
`shelf`,
`quantity`

requirements: get products with `sellstartdate` in 2006, AND their location with Total Availability less than 50.

Please help correct my CASE,(IS NULL in CASE) and JOIN for 3 tables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4vYg.jpg)

Comment: share your sql instead of sql query image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong then you looking some thing like below

```
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN ProductLine IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
              WHEN ProductLine='M' THEN 'Mountain'
              WHEN ProductLine='T' THEN 'Touring'
              ELSE Others END ProductLine,
              SellStartDate,
              [Location].LocationID,
              Availability AS 'Total Availability'
FROM Production.Product
INNER JOIN Production.ProductInventory ON Production.Product.ProductID=Production.ProductInventory.ProductID
INNER JOIN [Production].[Location] ON Production.Product.LocationID=[Production].[Location].LocationID
WHERE SellStartDate BETWEEN '1/1/2006' AND '31/12/2006'
AND Availability < 50
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got these messages: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Invalid column name 'LocationID'. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Ambiguous column name 'Name'.

Comment: @Ann please modify query according to your table structure . for `Name` use `Product.Name` in `SELECT` statement

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks again for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN ProductLine IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
                  WHEN ProductLine='M' THEN 'Mountain'
                  WHEN ProductLine='T' THEN 'Touring'
                  ELSE Others END ProductLine,
        SellStartDate
FROM Production.Product
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.